# Weird output while reading a .tar.gz file in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Please go a little Easy on me, As I am a newbie to hadoop and MapReduce.

I have a .tar.gz file that I am trying to read using mapReduce by writing a custom InputFormatter employing CompressionCodecfactory.

I read some document over Internet that CompressionCodecFactory can be used to read a .tar.gz file. hence I implemented that in my code.

The output that I get After running the code is absolute garbage.

A piece of my input file is provided below:

```
"MAY 2013          KOTZEBUE, AK"
"RALPH WIEN MEMORIAL AIRPORT (PAOT)"
"Lat:66° 52'N   Long: 162° 37'W   Elev (Ground) 30 Feet"
"Time Zone : ALASKA           WBAN: 26616    ISSN#: 0197-9833"
01,21,0,11,-11,3,11,54,0," ",4,  ,0.0,0.00,30.06,30.09,10.2,36,10.0,25,360,22,360,01
02,25,3,14,-9,5,12,51,0," ",4,  ,0.0,0.00,30.09,30.11,6.1,34,7.7,16,010,14,360,02
03,21,1,11,-12,7,11,54,0," ",4,  ,0.0,0.00,30.14,30.15,5.0,28,6.0,17,270,16,270,03
04,20,8,14,-10,11,13,51,0,"SN BR",4,  ,.001,.0001,30.09,30.11,8.6,26,9.2,20,280,15,280,04
05,29,19,24,-1,21,23,41,0,"SN BR",5,  ,0.6,0.06,30.11,30.14,8.1,20,8.5,22,240,20,240,05
06,27,19,23,-3,21,23,42,0,"SN BR",4,  ,0.1,0.01,30.14,30.15,8.7,19,9.4,18,200,15,200,06
```

The the output I get is quite weird:

```
��@(���]�OX}�s���{Fw8OP��@ig@���e�1L'�����sAm�
��@���Q�eW�t�Ruk�@��AAB.2P�V��    \L}��+����.֏9U]N �)(���d��i(��%F�S<�ҫ  ���EN��v�7�Y�%U�>��<�p���`]ݹ�@�#����9Dˬ��M�X2�'��\R��\1-    ���V\K1�c_P▒W¨P[Ö␤ÍãÏ2¨▒;O
```

Below is the Custom InputFormat and RecordReader code:

InputFormat

```
public class SZ_inptfrmtr extends FileInputFormat<Text, Text>
{

@Override
public RecordReader<Text, Text> getRecordReader(InputSplit split,
        JobConf job_run, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new SZ_recordreader(job_run, (FileSplit)split);
}

}
```

RecordReader:

```
public class SZ_recordreader implements RecordReader<Text, Text>
{
FileSplit split;
JobConf job_run;
boolean processed=false;

CompressionCodecFactory compressioncodec=null;   // A factory that will find the correct codec(.file) for a given filename.
public SZ_recordreader(JobConf job_run, FileSplit split)
{
    this.split=split;
    this.job_run=job_run;
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Text createKey() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Text();
}

@Override
public Text createValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Text();
}

@Override
public long getPos() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return processed ? split.getLength() : 0;
}

@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return processed ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}

@Override
public boolean next(Text key, Text value) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FSDataInputStream in=null;
    if (!processed)
    {
        byte [] bytestream= new byte [(int) split.getLength()];
        Path path=split.getPath();
        compressioncodec=new CompressionCodecFactory(job_run);

        CompressionCodec code = compressioncodec.getCodec(path);  
        // compressioncodec will find the correct codec by visiting the path of the file and store the result in code
        System.out.println(code);

        FileSystem fs= path.getFileSystem(job_run);

        try
        {
            in =fs.open(path);
            IOUtils.readFully(in, bytestream, 0, bytestream.length);
            System.out.println("the input is " +in+ in.toString());
            key.set(path.getName());
            value.set(bytestream, 0, bytestream.length);
        }
        finally
        {
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
        }

        processed=true;

        return true;


    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Could anybody please point out the flaw..

Comment: What is output for `System.out.println(new CompressionCodecFactory(job_run).toString());` ? May be you just have no codec for `zg.rat.`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a codec for `.gz`, but no codec for `.tar`.

Your `.tar.gz` is being decompressed to `.tar`, but it's still a [tarball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29), and not something understood by the Hadoop system.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be stuck there in mapper and reducer class communication, To work with compressed  files in MapReduce you need to set some configuration options for your job. These  classes
are mandatory to set in driver class:

```
conf.setBoolean("mapred.output.compress", true);//Compress The Reducer Out put
conf.setBoolean("mapred.compress.map.output", true);//Compress The Mapper Output
conf.setClass("mapred.output.compression.codec",
codecClass,
CompressionCodec.class);//Compression codec for Compresing mapper output
```

The only difference between a MapReduce job that works with uncompressed versus
compressed IO are these three annotated lines.

```
I read some document over Internet that CompressionCodecFactory can be used to read a .tar.gz file. hence I implemented that in my code.
```

Even Compression codec do better over, but there are many codec for this purpose most one is LzopCodec and SnappyCodec for possible big data.. you can find a Git for LzopCodec here :https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hadoop/compression/lzo/LzopCodec.java